# dynamic_cast Template class with "Known" Inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have a type that inherits from a template-defined type.  The template-defined type is guaranteed to have a given base class.  What I want to do is to be able to dynamic_cast or otherwise find types in a container that match my derived type, irrespective of the template parameter.

```
// A bunch of classes exist which inherit from Base already.
class Base{};
class Base2 : public Base {};
class BaseN : public Base {};

// Some new classes can inherit from any Base-derived class,
// but also have special attributes (i.e. function "f").
template<typename T = Base>
class Derived : public T
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, 
        "Class must inherit from a type derived from Base.")

    public:
        void f();
};

//
// Now process a collection of Base pointers.  
//

std::vector<Base*> objects;

// The vector may contain classes that are not "Derived".
// I only care about the ones that are.
// I want the cast here to return non-null for Derived<Base>, 
// Derived<Base2>, Derived<BaseN>, but null for Base, Base2, etc.

// This will be Null, Good.
objects.push_back(new Base)
auto dcast0 = dynamic_cast<Derived<Base>*>(objects[0]);

// This will be Non Null, Good.
objects.push_back(new Derived<Base>);
auto dcast1 = dynamic_cast<Derived<Base>*>(objects[1]);

// This will be Null, BAD! HELP!
objects.push_back(new Derived<Base2>);
auto dcast2 = dynamic_cast<Derived<Base>*>(objects[2]);
```

Comment: Derived<Base2> != Derived<Base>. They are completly different types, so dcast2 is correctly set to null. One way to go around this is to make Derived inherit from another class, lets say DerivedBase, and then dynamic cast to that.

Comment: You're kind of mixing two different concepts together: runtime polymorphism and compile-time polymorphism. You could go as Creris suggested or consider refactoring your code in order to avoid comparing different template types

Comment: Derived<Base2> and Derived<Base> are NOT completely different types in that they both ultimately inherit from Base.  That is, I could cast either of them to a Base* successfully.  I am not arguing that the casts were wrong, only illustrating what I desired from some possible solution.  Indeed, it was the mixing of the compile-time guarantee that both inherit from Base and both have the same interface defined by Derived that I would have liked to exploit at runtime.  Using the suggested DerivedBase is a simple solution here that ultimately addresses 90% of what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Creris' in comments, you need a base class is that is common to all your `Derived<T>` template classes when `T` is not `Base`. In addition, the inheritance to `Base` itself should be virtual, so that there is only a single `Base` instance when `Derived<>` is instantiated.

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base () = default; };
struct Base2 : virtual Base {};

struct DerivedBase : virtual Base {};

template <typename BASE = Base>
struct Derived : DerivedBase, BASE {};

    Base *b = new Derived<Base2>;
    assert(dynamic_cast<DerivedBase *>(b));
```

However, you could use template specialization so that the common base class is actually `Derived<Base>` itself.

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base () = default };
struct Base2 : virtual Base {};

template <typename = Base> struct Derived;

template <>
struct Derived<Base> : virtual Base {};

template <typename BASE>
struct Derived : Derived<Base>, BASE {};

    Base *b = new Derived<Base2>;
    assert(dynamic_cast<Derived<> *>(b));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZKxTsMwEIb3PMUpDE0RVLTd0uABWFiYugGqXMcBQxJH8TkIofLq5eykoUFUiif77r/7/rMtquryRYj9mSpFblMJidIGa8kLFvzGGilQ18cR/KykKjPNgj3JrUC44UbCFzSqRstz@HbnaArXkMqM2xxXsFsFR9oFxL24rR3mH/7LByiLKufYOSh5IYng0gxEzo2BO1mrRqYDKTv07ZJJW/C3fwC0Gq1SyMh4e3TLYBrHQluEJIHwHicGeJ4D37oQvkpf/lSGK1@xC074XP@1QQYGhi5g3VENclRiQ/PIGiPPV2azJdFGZ15MWhbHDc8tbXunvyu89bdRWIP0AA4CWa0Lb3UWTsnhqGHXoAyEbusfPI3W05kbhkooNnkqJ8dDqxKh4KoE39F3an@Ot3zOQG/f6GxI2u1mlTWvNJh4j0r54d2RN25RQyq4wSv3fz6JSLfhzsnhwtg5i7oej1fPVNPKLxlNc7J9XzxgzMcw5j1jPo7hv/gQtBgDWvSgxXjQwxC0PAVqtUe0ZU9bdrTdfv8D)

Comment: I was hoping someone had some voodoo, but back to basics to get things wired up.  Appreciate the sanity check!

Comment: @DiB Voodoo added.